# Getting textbox value from a different form

Tags: c#

Form 1:

```
public partial class FrmMain : Form
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();

    public FrmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Use = String.Empty;

    private void btnLogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Use = txtUsername.Text;
    }
}
```

Form 2:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string theDate1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string theDate2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dateTimePicker1.MaxDate = dateTimePicker2.Value;

    FrmMain Form = new FrmMain();
    string username = Form.Use;

    if (cboFrom.Text != "" && cboTo.Text != "" && Adults.Text != "" && Children.Text != "" && dateTimePicker2.Value > dateTimePicker1.Value)
    {
        string q = "insert into Booking([Departure], [Return], [From], [To],[Adults],[Children],[Username]) values ('"
            + theDate1.ToString() + "', '" + theDate2.ToString() + "','" + cboFrom.Text + "','"
            + cboTo.Text + "','" + Children.Text + "','" + Adults.Text + "', '" + username + "')";

        dosomething(q);
        MessageBox.Show("Success");
    }
}
```

Im trying to make a program where u can record data to a database. I need to get the username I input on a textbox into another form but the username wont record into the ms access database.

Comment: `FrmMain Form = new FrmMain()` creates a new instance of your `FrmMain` class. You need to reference the one that already exists...the one where you entered the user's name.

Comment: `FrmMain Form1 = new FrmMain()  string username = Form1.Use`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you create a new instance of `FrmMain` in this line:

```
FrmMain Form = new FrmMain();
```

An alternative would be to pass the string when calling `Form2`. Like

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.Username = txtUsername.Text;
f2.ShowDialog();
```

Or another way is make your string `Use` static and call it from `Form2` without creating a new instance:

```
// FrmMain
public static string Use { get; set; }

// Form2
string username = FrmMain.Use;
```